# How to test a Kafka Streams Function with TestTopologyDriver?

Tags: java, testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Function to test:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process() {

    return processKStream-> processKStream
            .filter((k, v) -> v.getId() > 10;
}
```

Test setup:

```
TestTopology testTopology = new TestTopology()

KStream<String, String> processKStream= streamsBuilder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));

testTopology.process().apply(processKStream);

topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(streamsBuilder.build());

processTaskTestInputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic("input-topic", stringSerde.serializer(), stringSerde.serializer());
processTaskTestOutputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic("HERE GOES TOPIC NAME", stringSerde.deserializer(), stringSerde.deserializer());
```

My function "process" does not output a topic and therefore I do not have a name for it. How would I test this function?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your method just operates on a stream. It does not generate any output topic since filter operation is stateless.

You provide the output topic name on your own, for your own tests unrelated to a specific processor. Then test the output topic contains the data you want